# Generic/native Object in Java

Tags: java, object, native

I'm looking for a Java native object which has two strings attributes.

What i would like to obtain is :

```
MagicObject myObj = new MagicObject();
myObjet.setFstAttributes("str1");
myObjet.setScdAttributes("str2");
```

Could you notice me an Object to use ? (An object which is in the java util or other)

Thanks for your help,
jérémy

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457775/does-java-need-tuples) and others. There are a million implementations, none in the JDK. (Except, apparently, `AbstractMap.SimplyEntry`, but meh.)

Comment: native code is precompiled C header file   that you invoke from  java bytecode. Do you want to ofuscate  the code? If is related to performance it does not worth it

Comment: Actually I think the question should have been: "How to create a new class with some methods". But I hope not ;0

Comment: Is there a Java object that accepts two Strings. An object already exists in Which JDK
But I got my answer with user949300 and Dave.

Rightly I wanted to avoid creating an object ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java 6 or higher, Check out `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.  In your example, you'd want a `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>.`